# How to delete Panel variant programmatically

Tags: 7, panels, chaos-tool-suite

I have a "node_view" panel pane, with a few variants.

Say a variant called `node_view_panel_context_9`, and I would like to delete this variant programmatically using code (from a hook_update_N hook to be specific).

What are the correct API functions/methods to use?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do this recently. If the variant is exported to code (like in a Feature) this will revert it. Otherwise it will just delete it.

```
   function MY_MODULE_update_N() {
     ctools_include('export');
     $page = ctools_export_crud_load('page_manager_handlers', 'node_view__test123');
     ctools_export_crud_delete('page_manager_handlers', $page);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this was not it. `ctools_export_crud_load`'s first argument is table name in database. But most of the handlers I have are not in that table or in the database anywhere. I came to the conclusion that it's not stored in DB unless it's overridden, so if you just remove the handler from your feature then it goes away after a cc all. Would be great to get confirmation on this from someone who knows ctools storage logic.

Comment: Following the docs at http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21ctools%21includes%21export.inc/function/ctools_export_crud_delete/7 and in practice in fact, simply deleting the snippet defining any ctools defined handler (like a Page in Page Manager in my case) from your exported code in fact removes it from the Drupals. They are not stored in one of the page_manager_.. tables, and I did not find anything but the *rendered* assets in cache_.. tables.  Long and the short: manually edit your export code and deploy! (backup first)